# jQuery wait for an AJAX request to be completed before refreshing the page

Tags: ajax, jquery

I've got the following jQuery:

```
$("#delete_products").click(function() {
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function() {
        var pid = $(this).val();
        $.get('delete_product.php',{pid: pid});
    });
    location.reload();
});
```

There is a problem with this since the page doesn't wait for the AJAX request to be completed (**MULTIPLE AJAX REQUESTS**), and refreshes the page immediately and makes the AJAX request to not run and fail.

How can I do that the page will only refresh when it done loading?

I've been given this code:

```
$("#delete_products").click(function () {
    var promises = [];
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function () {
        var pid = $(this).val();
        promises.push($.get('delete_product.php', {
            pid: pid
        }));
    });
    $.when.apply($, promises).done(function () {
        location.reload();
    });
    return false;
});
```

But this solution just doesn't work.

any suggestions?

Comment: the second code looks correct at first glance - in what way does it "not work" ?

Comment: An answer suggesting the use of the success function of get() was voted down. Why is that not an option here?

Comment: @cars10 because the OP apparently wants to wait for multiple AJAX requests (although the question is poorly written and only hints at that in the code, and not in the text).  The 'success' answer gave completely incorrect syntax for even handling one request.

Comment: @Alnitak makes the page reload and doesnt delete the items. Poor described? what information do you need?

Comment: @kfirba check your console for errors, I can see nothing immediately wrong with the `.when` based code - that's exactly how it should be written.

Comment: @kfirba the text of your question completely omits the important part that you're wanting to submit _multiple_ AJAX requests, one for each `:checked` element, and then only reload after they're _all_ complete.  I got that from the code, but other people obviously didn't.

Comment: @Alnitak That's because I thought it was obvious, I guess it's not, therefore, im going to edit the post.

Comment: @kfirba did you consider that maybe it's your `delete_product.php?pid=...` that doesn't work?  p.s. you should use `POST` for scripts that change state, not `GET`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! The delete_product.php page worked perfectly fine.
I'm trying to do what @sUp suggested now.

Comment: @kfirba IMHO it would be (initially) more productive to figure out why the current code doesn't work.  I really can't see anything wrong with it here, unless it happens you're running a really old version of jQuery.  Perhaps you should pass `ev` to the handler and call `ev.preventDefault()` right up top.  Also, if your `#delete_products` is an `<a>` element it'll automatically trigger a page change and if your current code throws an exception then your `return false` will never be seen.

Comment: @kfirba to test that, comment out the `location.reload()` line and see if you _still_ get a reload.  If you do, you've got some other problem.

Comment: @kfirba Did the array method work out for you? Have you checked the example in my answer?

Comment: @MarkusHofmann I did use your array method. Sorry for the late response, I had urgent things to take care of.

If you want I can post my solution which is slightly different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code seems like it should work, but i would recommend to delete all products with one call by passing array of ids.

less work for the browser, less work for the server, faster results.

---

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```
$("#delete_products").click(function () {
    var ids = [];

    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function () {
        ids.push($(this).val());
    });

    $.post('delete.php', { 'ids': ids } }).done(function() {
        alert('hells yeah!');
    });

    return false;
});
```

and as for the server side:

```
$commaSeperatedIds = explode(',', $_POST['ids']);

mysql_query('DELETE FROM products WHERE id IN('.mysql_real_escape_string($commaSeperatedIds).')');
```

Comment: Sounds good, any suggestion how to do that?
I don't know how to pass an array using $.get() or how to use the array after it will be passed in the php file.

Comment: @kfirba Example: Pass `myparam=JSON.stringify(['array'])` as a parameter and then in PHP use `json_decode($_GET['myparam'])` to get the array.

Comment: @sUp I have never worked with JSON. I really have NO idea what the results are going to be. Let's say that I got an array named "ids" with al of the IDS that i want to delete. How do I pass it using the `$.post()` method? in the file `delete_product.php` how do I take this $_POST variable and run a loop to scan the array elements?

Comment: NB: the PHP hack that allows you to send an array parameter is not a CGI standard feature.  Over server-side languages do not support it.

Comment: @Alnitak didn't know that, thanks. guess i'll be using json from now on

Answer (score 0):

### Possible Solution #1:

The `async` parameter could help. Set it to false.

Since you`re using the $.get() function, this is done with:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    async: false
});
```

With the $.ajax() function, you'd simply set it like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: ...,
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {}
});
```

More info on this can be found [**here**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings).

### Possible Solution #2:

Use the [`.success()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#callback-functions) callback hook *OR* `.complete()` if you want to refresh the page no mather if the request failed or not.

```
$.get('delete_product.php',{pid: pid}).success(function(response)
{
    location.reload();
});
```

**Happy coding!**

### Edit:

The questioner seems to prever sUP's answer. I'd like to provide an example of how to achieve the desired functionality with jQuery:

```
$("#delete_products").click(function()
{
    var products = [];

    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function()
    {
        var pid = $(this).val();
        products.push(pid);
    });

    $.post('delete_products.php', {'products': products}).done(function()
    {
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

**If you prefer to use JSON for the post data, try:**

```
$('#delete_products').click(function()
{
    var products = [];
    
    $(':checkbox:checked').each(function()
    {
        products.push($(this).val());
    });

    // Convert the products array into JSON
    products = JSON.stringify(products);

    $.post('delete_products.php', {'products': products}).done(function()
    {
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

In PHP you need to parse the json string as follows:

```
<?php
// This creates an associative array from the JSON string
$delete_products = json_decode($_POST['products'], true);

// Use explode to make a comma separated string from the array
// for use in a SQL SELECT query:
$delete_products = explode(',', $delete_products);
```

Info about `json_decode` can be found in the [PHP Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

JSON.stringify is not supported in older browsers. Include [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) if you need cross browser support.

Comment: This can't be the asnwer. I want to send multiple AJAX requests and not only one. Therefore, this code can't help me at all

Comment: @kfirba Why can't it help? **Just use the `success()` callback in whatever ajax function you use?!**

Comment: @MarkusHofmann he wants to wait for _multiple_ AJAX queries to finish.  Using `.when` is the right way of doing this.

Comment: @MarkusHofmann unfortunately, your example of how to use `$.when` is incorrect when you don't know in advance how many `...` there are going to be.  Which is why the OP's (apparently correct) code uses `$.when.apply($, array)`.  Also, it's more usual to use `.done` instead of `.then` - the latter is used when you want to return an alternate promise instead of just registering a callback.

Comment: @Alnitak I'll improve the example.

Comment: Ok, added an example for the desired solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use "success" parameter of "get"

EDIT: add counter of requests.

```
total_requests = $(":checkbox:checked").length;
total_success = 0;

...
$.get('delete_product.php',{pid: pid}, function (data, status, xx) {
    ...
    total_success++;
    if (total_success >= total_requests) {
        location.reload();
    }
});
...
```

Comment: This can't be the asnwer. I want to send multiple AJAX requests and not only one. Therefore, this code can't help me at all

Comment: The line with "..." means where you have to check if all your requests have succeded... Keep a counter or something.

Answer (score -1):

I too believe that the desired result can probably be achieved best by collecting the product IDs and then sending a single Ajax call to take care of them all.

But since the OP put the interesting question forward of how to handle multiple Ajax requests and wait for them all to be finished I have looked at the `when()` method again and it seems to me that the original syntax is still faulty.

According to the jQuery manual `when()` is a method and therefore requires to be called with one or more argument(s) in parentheses. I have not worked with promises yet and I have not tested anything but I assume that something like the following might bring at least a different result:

```
$("#delete_products").click(function () {
    var promises = [];
    $(":checkbox:checked").each(function () {
        var pid = $(this).val();
        promises.push($.get('delete_product.php', {
            pid: pid
        }));
    });
    $.when(promises).done(function () {
        location.reload();
    });
    return false;
});
```

As I said before, I still have not quite grasped the `promises` mechanisms/syntax yet ...

In the original version `$.when` does not have any meaningful context to work on, The `apply()` method does provide context but only *after* when has done its (unseccessful) work already.

Comment: `$.when.apply($, array)` is the correct way to call `$.when` with an array of promises of unknown length.  Strictly speaking, the first parameter (`$`) will be ignored because `$.when` doesn't care what `this` is.

Comment: @Alnitak Thanks for answering my question and clarifying that point to me! I think I got it now: `when`is not actually called itself, rather `apply()` calls 'when' (in apply() it will appear as `this`) with its given parameters ...